# Remove top margin from BrowseFragment in Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, browsefragment

How can I remove blank space, as shown in dotted box in below image from  `BrowseFragment`. I managed to remove search button and title. Although, I also want to remove blank space and move video row at top of screen.

Is there any way to do this?

I tried setting following in my AppTheme, but I doubt it helps:

```
    <item name="browseRowsMarginTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="browsePaddingTop">0dp</item>
```

[image]

Comment: You can do this by modifying `leanback layouts` itself.

Comment: I had tried changing following: `FrameLayout topHeader = (FrameLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.browse_headers_dock);
        topHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);` But its not removing that space. can you suggest which layout I should look to edit?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using it's `dimens.xml` which is provided in `v17 Lean Back` library.

> `Follow the steps below first.`

1. Go to your `sdk` -> `extras` -> `android` -> `support` -> `v17` -> `leanback` -> `res` -> `values`.
2. From their copy `dimens.xml` file into your current leanback project `values` folder.
3. Now you have the `dimens.xml` file inside your project `values` folder.
4. Open that file and find below `dimen`.

> Default value may be `167dp` given.

```
<dimen name="lb_browse_rows_margin_top">167dp</dimen>
```

> So change it to around `30dp` or as per your need.

```
<dimen name="lb_browse_rows_margin_top">30dp</dimen>
```

You will get the rows up in `Browse Fragment`.

Comment: Could you please add to the answer steps, how you found out that this name was exactly `lb_browse_rows_margin_top`?

Comment: for easy lookup use => cmd + shift + f (global search on mac, look for windows) and then paste "lb_browse_rows_margin_top" to get the desired file suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to remove the header margin in only the fragment instead of globally overwrite the BrowseFragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    FrameLayout containerDock = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.browse_container_dock);
    FrameLayout.MarginLayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.MarginLayoutParams) containerDock.getLayoutParams();
    Resources resources = inflater.getContext().getResources();
    int newHeaderMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    int offsetToZero = -resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.lb_browse_rows_margin_top);
    params.topMargin = offsetToZero+newHeaderMargin;
    containerDock.setLayoutParams(params);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: where do we have to add it?

Comment: @AparAmin extend the BrowseFragment and overwrite the onCreateView method

public class CustomBrowseFragment extends BrowseFragment{}

Answer (score -1):

the IanZ solution works perfectly. Other way to get the main container is 
`FrameLayout containerDock = getView().findViewById(R.id.browse_container_dock);` in the main fragment without override `oncreateView` method.